# Why does the matched regex string not stored even though it matches?

Tags: c, regex

This is the code:

```c
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    regex_t regex;
    regmatch_t regmatch[2];
    char * scanner = "hello";

    if (regcomp(&regex, "^[:alpha:]", 0) == regexec(&regex, scanner, 2, regmatch, 0)) {
        printf("YES\n");

        char * result;
        result = (char *) malloc(regmatch[1].rm_eo - regmatch[1].rm_so);
        strncpy(result, &scanner[regmatch[1].rm_so], regmatch[1].rm_eo - regmatch[1].rm_so);
        printf("%s\n", result);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OH NO\n");
    }
}
```

The output is always is "YES" but the next lines doesn't print matched string even though it should because it the regex matches. When I tried `strcpy(result, &scanner[regmatch[1].rm_so]);` instead of `strncpy`, the next line after "YES" is the matched string but there is '?' before the string, like "?hello" and I tried fixing this by adding 1 in the result malloc and the output is still the same "?hello". I have also have this program:

```c
int main(void)
{
    regex_t preg;


    char *string = "12";

    regmatch_t pmatch[2];

    char *result;

    if (regcomp(&preg, ".*\\(^[0-9]*\\).*", 0) == regexec(&preg, string, 2, pmatch, 0))
    {
        result = (char*)malloc(pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so);
        strncpy(result, &string[pmatch[1].rm_so], pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so);
        printf("a matched substring \"%s\" is found.\n", result);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NO\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice in this program, the regex pattern is inside like so `.*\\(^[0-9]*\\).*` instead of `^[0-9]*` because when I use the shorter one, it doesn't print the matched string but the longer one does print and without `?` before the matched string.

So how do I properly store a matched substring with regex and print it in C? How come `.*\\(^[0-9]*\\).*` works but `^[0-9]*` doesn't? I also noticed when I did the regex character `?` for optional/lazy, it doesn't seem to compile the regex pattern. Are there any regex characters that cannot not be compiled by the C regex compiler that otherwise would in other regex compilers? I also tried `\?` and `\\?`, and still no luck.

Comment: The [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) function might not terminate the string it copies. You *do* remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null terminated** byte strings*?

Comment: I also recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line while monitoring all involved variables and their values.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are having (at least with the first snippet of code) is that you are referring to match group 1, which is for the first group subexpression (and you don't have one).  That means normal result.  Probably what you want is group 0 and not 1 (which always exists, delimiting the whole matched regexp)  but as you post only a snippet, and not the complete code (your snippet doesn't compile, at least if you don't put the correct `#include` statements at the beginning)  there's no way to dig on it further.

Regular expression groups refer to the regexp subexpressions delimited by parenthesis (the left parenthesis marks the group number position)

Read the manual page for `regcomp(3)` or `regexec(3)` for a complete explanation on how the groups work, and how they are included in regular expressions.